# Цикл на react jsx

Tags: reactjs, jsx

как мне в цикле `jsx` получит разметку подобного формата:

```
<div class="grid">grid</div>
<div class="block">
    <div class="list">list</div>
    <div class="list">list</div>
    <div class="list">list</div>
</div>
<div class="grid">grid</div>
<div class="block">
    <div class="list">list</div>
    <div class="list">list</div>
    <div class="list">list</div>
</div>
<div class="grid">grid</div>
<div class="block">
    <div class="list">list</div>
    <div class="list">list</div>
    <div class="list">list</div>
</div>
<div class="grid">grid</div>
<div class="block">
    <div class="list">list</div>
    <div class="list">list</div>
    <div class="list">list</div>
</div>
```

мой вариант условия в цикле:

```
{item.map((value, key) => {
    {key % 4 == 0 ? (
      <div className="grid">grid</div>
    ) : (
     <div className="list">list</div>
    )}
})}
```

Но это не желаемый результат

Comment: А можно больше шаблона? Хочется увидеть откуда `class="grid"` появился :)

Comment: @gil9red исправил

Answer (score 0):

Алгоритм данного вопроса:

```
{item.map((value, key, array) => {
 return (
   <React.Fragment key={key}>
     {key % 4 === 0 && (
       <React.Fragment>
        <div class="grid">{value.itemId}</div>
        <div class="block">
        {array.slice(key + 1, key + 4).map((val, i) => {
         return <div class="list" key={i}>{val.itemId}</div>
          })
        }
        </div>
       </React.Fragment>
       )}
       </React.Fragment>
       )
       })
```

Comment: React.Fragment можно написать и короче: <></>

Comment: @NeedHate и в правду, но не с атрибутами

Comment: нельзя использовать индекс массива в качестве ключа